# FOSCommentBundle Thread

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

i have installed the FOSCommentBundle, everythings works the input comment display as expected but i want to display 1 thread per entity, so i got many planning with different url, like this : /planning/id . But whenever i post a comment for example in the planning/1 . I got a permalink created in the thread entity. But when i want go to the planning/2, it's display the comment of the planning/1 thread and won't create another permalink for planning/2.

I don't understand what i've done wrong. So if you have any clue for my problem, i will be grateful.

I created 2 entity :

```
<?php

namespace Simon\CommentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Comment as BaseComment;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Model\SignedCommentInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Comment extends BaseComment implements SignedCommentInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Thread of this comment
     *
     * @var Thread
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Simon\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread")
     */
    protected $thread;

    /**
     * Author of comment
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Simon\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $author;

    public function setAuthor(UserInterface $author)
    {
        $this->author = $author;
    }

    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function getAuthorName()
    {
        if (null === $this->getAuthor()) {
            return 'Anonymous';
        }

        return $this->getAuthor()->getUsername();
    }
}

<?php

namespace Simon\CommentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\CommentBundle\Entity\Thread as BaseThread;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Thread extends BaseThread
{
    /**
     * @var string $id
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And i just followed the documentation to display the comment on my planning twig view :

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Planning de {{app.user.name}}</h2>
<div class="row">
    <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Lundi</th>
                        <th>Mardi</th>
                        <th>Mercredi</th>
                        <th>Jeudi</th>
                        <th>Vendredi</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Responsable</th>
                        {% for i in 1..5 %}
                        {% set assigned_user = null %}
                        {% for user in users if user.planningday == i%}
                            {% set assigned_user = user %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td>
                        {% if not assigned_user is null %}
                        <a href="{{path('fos_user_profile_show_name', {'username':assigned_user.username})}}">  {{assigned_user.name}} {{assigned_user.lastname}}</a>
                        {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">Description</th>
                        {% for i in 1..5 %}
                        {% set assigned_user = null %}
                        {% for user in users if user.planningday == i%}
                            {% set assigned_user = user %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        <td>
                        {% if not assigned_user is null %}
                            {{assigned_user.planningcontent}} 
                        {% endif %}
                        </td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
     <a href="{{path('planningsub', {id:planning.id})}}">Inscription</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    {% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'foo'} %}
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post code of what you've tried so we can see what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<div class="row">
    {% include 'FOSCommentBundle:Thread:async.html.twig' with {'id': 'planning'~planning.id} %}
</div>
```